# How can I generate a thumbnail of a specific page in a PDF on the command line in OS X?

Tags: macos, pdf, thumbnails

I need to be able to generate a png thumbnail of a specific page of a PDF document in OS X.

I can use 'qlmanage -p MyFile.pdf -o outputDir -s1000' to get a 1000-pixel wide PNG of the first page. This works perfectly, and is almost exactly what I need. The only missing piece is being able to specify a certain page number of the PDF.

Can this be done with qlmanage, or some other command-line utility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) ought to be able to help:

```
convert -resize 10000x10000 MyFile.pdf[2] MyOutput.png
```

Where `2` is the page number. Enjoy!

Comment: ImageMagick seems broken. I downloaded the pre-built binary for OS X, but I can't get convert to work at all. This command: "convert -resize 1000x1000 DroboGuide.pdf MyOutput.png" gives me this error: "Postscript delegate failed `DroboGuide.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/645.". The file does exist in the current working directory.

Comment: It turns out that the reason ImageMagick was failing is that I need GhostScript installed in order to use ImageMagick with PDFs. I can't use GhostScript because it's GPL, and furthermore I ran into numerous problems trying to install it just to try it out. Even if we wanted to buy the non-GPL commercial license, the ImageMagick / GhostScript combo adds too much size, complexity, and new support requirements to bundle with our software. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Comment: Well, in that case, you’ll probably need to create your own tool to do the same. OS X has built-in support for PDFs, so I’m sure there’s a way to render a specific page into an image. Check out CGPDFDocument and friends:http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFDocument/Reference/reference.html

Comment: That's how I was doing it before. The problem is that there is a memory leak in the PDF generation in Core Image (confirmed by Apple as radar #8668407), so I was going to try to switch to a command line that ran as its own process, instead of rendering the PDF thumbnail from in my process (which eventually runs out of memory).

Comment: You could split your own PDF thumbnail-generating code into a separate process, then include it as a command-line utility with your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Aspose.Pdf` to generate a thumbnail (or image) of any page. Very reliable and generates a perfect image (as good as Acrobat). Only downside is it takes ~20 SECONDS to generate a single thumbnail. And that sucks. Code is as follows:

```
    Document document = new Document(pdfPath);
    Page page = document.Pages[pageNum];
    document.RemoveMetadata();
    page.Flatten();
    page.SendTo(new PngDevice(page.PageInfo.Width, page.PageInfo.Height), pngPath);
    document.Dispose();
```